# Implementing GPS location into markers on a single image

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to associate parts of a picture (markers) with GPS in Android.

These tutorials only showed how to get current location. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/GeolocationPermissions.html http://vinnysoft.blogspot.com/2009/10/location-manager-examples.html

Here's the idea : I'm making a map application which will have markers. These markers will have location associated with it.

Here's the problem : I'm having difficulties in associating the markers with location. Getting current location (lat. long.) can be done using the tutorial. But adding markers along with its location is the problem. How to add more markers with their respective location?

Here's the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainMap extends Activity {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    TouchImageView image = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.overview);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                    MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                    new MyLocationListener()
);
         showCurrentLocation();
}

protected void showCurrentLocation() {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                String message = String.format(
                        "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                        location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
                );

                Toast.makeText(MainMap.this, message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                String message = String.format(

                        "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",

                        location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()

                );

                Toast.makeText(MainMap.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {

                Toast.makeText(MainMap.this, "Provider status changed",

                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                Toast.makeText(MainMap.this,

                        "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",

                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                Toast.makeText(MainMap.this,

                        "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",

                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I have to assume that you do have a GoogleMap object included in your activity to add a Marker to.

Also, I highly recommend you check the [Android Dev website](http://d.android.com) to set Google Play Services up for using not only the Google Maps API for Android but also it will improve the location retrieval by making use of WiFi and the service provider along with the GPS to lock in the coordinates faster.

Once that's done, the same Maps API provides the Marker object to be added to the map.

It should be something like this:

```
    Marker mMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(
        new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(knownLoc.getLatitude(), knownLoc.getLongitude())
            .icon(...) //android dev website provides all details
            ...;
```

You have a class MarkerOptions that lets you set everything regarding a marker. Once you have that set up, you call the method addMarker() in the GoogleMap object that will return a Marker object. With the returned Marker object you can update its location, the icon, etc. That way you don't have to clean the map, and re-create the marker and all other objects in order to update the map.

Good luck and I still recommend to go through the link I suggested to use the most updated and working code for your purpose. Plus it's explained in detail.

Comment: Uhh I tried using GoogleMap quite a while ago, but it wasn't the marker I wanted.. I wanted markers, each made up of 4 points for every "slot" in the image